# I can understand what i did wrong in the SQL query and why its not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
WITH
 c1 AS
 (SELECT x.asset_server_controller AS controller
        ,x.asset_environment AS env
        ,x.pager_creation_date || ' ' || x.pager_creation_time AS ts
        ,+1 AS TYPE
    FROM hub_asr_report x
   WHERE x.asset_environment IS NOT NULL
     AND x.asset_server_controller IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x.asset_server_controller AS controller
        ,x.asset_environment AS env
        ,x.pager_modify_date || ' ' || x.pager_modify_time AS ts
        ,-1 AS TYPE
    FROM hub_asr_report x
   WHERE x.asset_environment IS NOT NULL
     AND x.asset_server_controller IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY ts, controller  
  ),

 c2 AS
 (SELECT controller
        ,ts AS starttime
        ,lead(ts) over(PARTITION BY controller ORDER BY ts) AS endtime
        ,SUM([ 1 ] - [ - 1 ]) over(PARTITION BY controller ORDER BY ts rows unbounded preceding) AS cnt
    FROM c1
  pivot(COUNT(TYPE) FOR TYPE IN([ 1 ], [ - 1 ])) AS p
   ORDER BY controller,starttime
 )
SELECT *
  FROM c2
 WHERE cnt > 0
 ORDER BY app, st
```

Basically this code needs to count when something happens at the same time in the same controller, I am having issues with the SUM function where I am not able to count the intervals of time while the first event start but did not end.

I'm getting the following error message :

> 936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>        *Cause:
>        *Action:
>        Error at Line: 26 Column: 8

which is the line that starts with `SUM`.

For some reason I am getting an error/mistake in that line. What is wrong and how to fix it?

```
nc01b.dc02  2015-08-26 09:30:47 1
nc01b.dc02  2015-08-26 09:32:47 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:11 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:12 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:13 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:13 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:19 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:20 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:20 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:18:21 1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:19:19 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:19:19 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:21:31 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:21:31 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:21:34 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:21:34 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:21:34 -1
nc02a.dc03  2015-08-26 12:21:35 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:32:28 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:32:30 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:16 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:21 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:24 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:25 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:25 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:26 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:34:30 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:02 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:06 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:10 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:10 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:10 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:11 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:14 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:36:22 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 16:38:11 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:00:36 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:02:14 -1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:10 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:11 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:14 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:15 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:16 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:17 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:18 1
nc01a.dc05  2015-08-26 17:04:44 1
```

This is the output of C1 query, the issue i am experiencing is with C2 when Im trying to count the number of events that happen simultaneously in the same Controller in the same. I want to know the exact number of events that happen in the same time to pin point that there is an issue there.
1 stands for an event start and -1 for an event finished.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Also please choose either MySQL or SQL Server, it cannot be both.

Comment: @Sergei `x.PAGER_CREATION_DATE|| ' ' || x.PAGER_CREATION_TIME  AS starttime,` => `CONCAT(PAGER_CREATION_DATE, ' ', x.PAGER_CREATION_TIME) AS starttime`

Comment: SQL server doesn't use the (standard) `||` operator. You need to use `+` to concatenate strings in SQL Server.

Comment: That's an oracle error code? Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: concatenate function doesn't work for me i get 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" Error

Comment: the problem seems the 1 in square brackets, like `[1]`. But I have the strong suspicion that you didn't write that yourself and that you have no idea what you are doing here.

Comment: CONCAT was only introduced in SQL Server 2012. On the other hand,  00904. 00000 is an Oracle error code, not SQL Server. @Sergei, what database system are you *really* using?

Comment: You should just name your columns something else than +1 and -1, because it seems that's what's causing your problems

Comment: @MattGibson Perhaps he copy-pasted a sql server statement to an oracle database ?

Comment: Im using OBI. and trying to execute the code in Oracle SQL developer. never said the code is mine, im new and trying to adjust it to my use.

Comment: For Oracle (and in standard SQL) `[` and `]` is invalid in an identifier. SQL Developer is just a SQL client application. You need to tell us which DBMS you are using. What do you get when you run `select * from v$version`?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

> SUM( [1]-[-1] )  OVER

It is syntactically incorrect.

If you want to use the column value which you are using in your **WITH** clause, i.e. +1 and -1 as "type", then mention the alias " type" in the analytic function **SUM() OVER()**.

Also, no need to put `+` while selecting `1`, simply use `1`. I hope you understand that you would have the column value always as `1` for all the rows.

I think you want something like:

```
SUM(type) OVER(...
```

> FOR type IN ( [1], [-1]))

Similar issue here too. You need to get rid of `[` and `]` which is an invalid identifier.

I prefer **SQL*Plus** where you could easily know where the error is coming from.

Comment: I have tried to set the default value of type to sum by, but it doesn't work. about the type variable it has 1 for event start and -1 for event end. maybe it will be best to try and learn how to built the function from scratch

Comment: You need to provide a test case. Understand, we don't have your tables and data to help you. Neither do we know what is your desired output. So edit your queation and post the create table and insert statements. And ahow your desired output.